# Explain the geometrical meaning of Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, svd

Suppose you have a 2x2 real-valued matrix, $\mathbf{M}$. If you perform a singular value decomposition (SVD), then Wikipedia and the internet tell me that this can be understood geometrically as a decomposition of $\mathbf{M}$ into a rotation, scaling and second rotation of the form:

$$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{U S V}^\mathrm{T}$$

where the $\mathrm{T}$ denotes transpose. Here, $\mathbf{V}^\mathrm{T}$ is the first rotation, $\mathbf{S}$ is the scaling matrix and $\mathbf{U}$ is the last rotation.

Wikipedia has this nice little graphic:

[image]

So, what I am trying to do is essentially reproduce this graphic in MATLAB. I have a unit circle represented as:

$$\mathbf{C} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1&0 \\ 0 
 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This can be plotted in MATLAB like this:

[image]

I then have some arbitrary shearing matrix which is given by:

$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.5&4 \\ 1 
 & 1.5
\end{bmatrix}$$

which represents an ellipse which can also be plotted in MATLAB:

[image]

So far so good because I can reproduce the top two images in the Wikipedia article.

If I do the SVD for $\mathbf{M}$ I can get:

$$\mathbf{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -0.9239&-0.3827 \\ -0.3827
 & 0.9239
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{S} = \begin{bmatrix}
 4.3523&0 \\ 0
 & 0.7467
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{V} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -0.1941&-0.9810 \\ -0.981
 & -0.1941
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Now, can someone explain what I need to do to produce the bottom two images from the Wikipedia article?**

I thought that I would just be able to plot the columns of $\mathbf{V}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{C}$ to get the rotated unit vectors for the bottom left image like so:

[image]

Next, I would plot the ellipse of $\mathbf{SC}$ to get the bottom right stretched image and I can apply $\mathbf{SV}^\mathrm{T}$ to the unit vectors to get:

[image]

This is clearly wrong though because the major axis of the dashed ellipse is much longer than the major axis of the solid ellipse representing $\mathbf{M}$. If I rotate the dashed ellipse, it will not match the solid ellipse.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the method you are using to take a matrix and plot it as an ellipse?

Comment: I am using a code segment from here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4705-error_ellipse

Specifically look at the function "getpoints". Calculate the eigenvalues and vectors of the matrix and sweep through a set of angles from 0 to 2*pi. Is that where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what that function does, but I think the Wikipedia graphic should be starting with (for example) $C$ being a unit circle, and then if $A$ is a matrix, $AC$ is applying $A$ to every point on that circle. You could plot this parametrically by taking the points $A(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ as $\theta$ varies.

Comment: Thanks. The two methods do give different answers and your answer is correct...seems weird. I thought there was only one way to transform a 2x2 matrix into an ellipse. Maybe that code is incorrrect....

Comment: @Joppy: That looks like an Answer; can you please post it as one so that we can get this question out of the unanswered queue?